# Standard notation for one-sided partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation

What is the standard way of denoting function's $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ one-sided partial derivatives
$$\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}h,$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}h,$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}h,$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}h?$$

Comment: I feel like something like $\frac{\partial^+}{\partial x}f(x,y)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dots$ would be acceptable, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: To best of my knowledge: there is no such "standard" way.

Comment: @Jack If these weren't partial derivatives, they would be [subderivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: It seems that OP is looking for some notations similar to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative

Comment: @Jack Huh, that is a strange one... I've never considered using $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ for derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is the same as in one dimension. If you have $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ you can define the one-sided derivative of $f$ at $a$ by
$$
f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h\text{ if it exists}.
$$
Here you see that $h\to 0^+$ is necessary otherwise $f$ isn't defined on $a+h$. Same goes for the derivative of $f$ at $b$ which is defined by
$$
f'(b)=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}\text{ if it exists.}
$$
You see that $h\to 0^+$ or $h\to 0^-$ depends on boundary point. It has to be chosen such that $f$ is defined for the small perturbed point.

In higher dimension you can simplify the problem a little bit. Let be $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$, $x\in\partial \Omega$ and $v\in\mathbb R^N\setminus\{0\}$. If there exists $\tilde{h}>0$ such that $f(x+hv)$ is defined for $h\in[0,\tilde{h})$ then we define the one-sided directional derivative as
$$
\partial_vf(x)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h}\text{ if it exists.}
$$
Here you see that $f$ to be defined in the $v$ direction for a small perturbation of $x$. And the same goes for the partial derivatives which are just special directional derivatives.