# Notation for Right hand derivative and Left hand derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

Are $f'(a^+)$ and $f'(a^-)$ the notations for RHD and LHD?

So Is RHD given by $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$ mean $f'(a+)$ ? and in the same way LHD given by $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}$$ mean $f'(a^-)$?

I got the doubt while studying the behavior of the function.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
  x^2 \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0. 
\end{cases}$$

Since this function is differentiable at $x=0$ as RHD and LHD both are equal to zero i.e., $f'(0^+)=f'(0^-)=f'(0)=0$.

But as far continuity of $f'(x)$ is concerned we have

$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases} 
  2 x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0,
\end{cases}$$

here $f'(0^+)$ and $f'(0^-)$ are not defined

Comment: First of all, what's the question?  And possibly related to [standard notation for one-sided partial derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2361558/272831).

Comment: My question is whether $f'(a^+)=\lim _{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ is Right Notation or is it $f'_{+}(a)$

Comment: No, it is not standard notation for $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+h)- f(a)}{h}$.  It is, however, standard notation for the limit as x goes to a of f'(x) which is what is intended here.

Comment: ok i was confused by seeing those notations here http://www.vitutor.com/calculus/derivatives/sided_derivative.html

Comment: Could you make it clearer what your question is?  (e.g. there are no question marks denoting the question, and no emphasis on any particular question)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt i edited my query plzz have a look.

Comment: Your edited question is still having notation issue. The notation for left hand right derivatives of $f$ is different from the left and right limits of the derivative $f'$. The notation $f'(a^{+}) $ represents right hand limit of $f'$ at $a$ and $f'_{+} (a) $ denotes right hand derivative of $f $ at $a$. Also note the basic result that *if $f'(a^{+}) $ exists then $f'_{+} (a) $ also exists and is equal to $f'(a^{+}) $* but the converse does not hold. Similar notation and remarks apply to left hand derivative of a function and left hand limit of derivative of a function.

Comment: $f'_{\mathrm d}(a)$ and $f'_{\mathrm s}(a)$ are less confusing.

Comment: Thank u @ParamanandSingh

Comment: @user251257: Dini derivatives perhaps add even more notation so that you have two numbers for left derivative and two numbers for right derivative. Dont know if it reduces confusion.

Comment: Also both your limit definitions must use $h\to 0^{+}$ instead of usual $h\to 0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yeah. Right

Comment: ok standard is that $h$ is a small positive real number right? so obviously $h$ approaches zero from right

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma not in real analysis. That would be $\varepsilon$ or $\delta$.

Comment: $h$ is just a symbol for a variable. If you write $h\to 0$ then you can't say anything about sign of $h$.  To emphasize sign of $h$ you need to write either $h\to 0^{+}$ or $h\to 0^{-}$. Also your line of thought is common in students and the typical belief is that $a-h<a<a+h$. Perhaps people tend to think that symbols are positive unless prefixed by a negative sign. One generally overcomes such beliefs with experience.

Comment: Here you can find a notation for one-sided derivatives:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability

Comment: @ParamanandSingh "Also note the basic result that if $f'(a^{+})$ exists then $f'_{+}(a)$ also exists and is equal to $f'(a^{+})$ but the converse does not hold". Perhaps you meant otherwise. Consider $f(x)=\begin{cases}-x, &x≤0\\ -x-1,& x>0 \end{cases}$. Clearly, $f'(0^+)=-1$ but $f'_{+}(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: In my example above, $f'(x)$ is defined for $x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. I guess, in your statement $f$ was differentiable at $a$, a priori and you were reinforcing that $f'$ can not have jump discontinuity at $a$.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha: I should have been explicit that $f$ needs to be continuous in the neighborhood of point $a$ as well.